# How do I change the \citeauthor command from "A and B" to "A & B" (or create a new command)

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm trying to create a large table for a review in APA-Style. The first column is supposed to be the authors, but `\citeauthor` gives the in-text citation style of "Author A and Author B" for two authors when they have to be separated by an "&" symbol.

I don't think there is a command in the package I'm using that lets me archive that (correct me if I'm wrong).

How can I override the `\citeauthor` command or create a new \cite command that gives out the right format when there are two authors?

I'm using BibLaTeX (`\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}`)

Answer (score 1):

Define a new `\citeauthornp` command based on [`apa.cbx`'s (ll. 435-442) definition of `\citeauthor`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/f6acbee08ed82c0f4f1cf59b377c64234854122f/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/cbx/apa.cbx#L435-L442) and then alias `finalnamdelim` to its `\parencite` definition.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimAlias[citeauthornp]{finalnamedelim}[parencite]{finalnamedelim}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthornp}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:author}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citeauthornp{sigfridsson}

Lorem \parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson & Ryde Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)]